# Excel How do I find duplicate value in each row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example table

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c | c |
| 2 | b | a | d | e |
| 3 | c | d | b | a |
| 4 | b | d | d | d |
| 5 | e | a | d | e |

1 row has duplicated value 'c', columns C, D.

4 row has duplicated value 'd', columns B, C, D.

5 row has duplicated value 'e', columns A, D.

I used COUNTIF function, that function need to base column, but duplicated value can occurred any columns.

So how do I find duplicate value in each row, using excel function?

Comment: It would be useful to clarify if you need a formula or if conditional formatting is an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FILTER()` with `COUNTIFS()` function.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:D1,COUNTIFS(A1:D1,A1:D1)>1,""),1)
```

If you have chance to have more than 1 duplicate values then wrap it with `TEXTJOIN()` to concatenate all values into single cell.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:D1,COUNTIFS(A1:D1,A1:D1)>1,""),1))
```

To use the formula as dynamic spill array use `BYROW()` function.

```
=BYROW(A1:D5,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(x,COUNTIFS(x,x)>1,""),1))))
```

[image]

Comment: I thought we cannot use `COUNTIFS` inside `BYROW`, since `x` is an array, not a range, but it works. Interesting. I was trying to use `MMULT` for doing the counts, but your approach is shorter.

Comment: @DavidLeal In case of lambda functions, name of ranges also behave as range. I do not research much more on it, but in practical I found it working as range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Conditional Formatting>> Highlight>> Duplicate Values
```

that highlights duplicate cells in each row